# Use noweb reference in eLisp code in source block in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming

I want to manipulate an org mode source block that is referenced with `noweb` in an eLisp source block:

```
#+name: conceptmap
#+begin_src org :results value raw :exports results
(ONE) {TWO} (THREE)
(FOUR) {FIVE} (SIX)
#+end_src

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :noweb yes :results output 
(downcase (<<conceptmap()>>)
#+end_src
```

The desired result is:

```
(one) {two} (three)
(four) {five} (six)
```

The actual result is:

```
(downcase ((ONE) {TWO} (THREE)
(downcase ((FOUR) {FIVE} (SIX))
```

Why is it that the function `downcase` is not executed, and why is it that it is repeated? What is `<<conceptmap()>>` in reality? Can it be treated like a string or text block?

Comment: Have you settled on `noweb` for some reason that is not to be seen in your MWE? Otherwise you can refer to the org block's content with `:var str=conceptmap` in the header, change the `results` type to st. like value and evaluate `(downcase str)`.

Comment: Thanks, @mutbuerger. I have settled with your suggestion. If you nonetheless know an answer to my question, I'd be interested as the `noweb` approach looks promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to your problem.

Your file should look like this

```
#+name: conceptmap
#+begin_src org  :exports none
 (ONE) {TWO} (THREE) 
 (FOUR) {FIVE} (SIX)
#+end_src

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :noweb yes 
  (downcase "
    <<conceptmap2>>
   "
  )
#+end_src
```

Pay close attention to the ", as your original "input" would be parsed directly and strings like (ONE) would be interpreted as functions.

Another extremely important point is that the noweb reference must be on its own line as it seems there is either a bug, or an underdocumented limitation on the noweb expansion algorithm (I have no idea if the limitation is woth fixing )

I have a little example of what happens if the noweb reference is in its own line.

```
 #+name: test
 #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (let ((a 1)
        (b 2)
        (c 3))
    (+ a b c))
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes
  (+ 4 <<test>>)
#+END_SRC
```

which get expanded as

```
(+ 4 (let ((a 1)
(+ 4       (b 2)
(+ 4       (c 3))
(+ 4   (+ a b c)))
```